# Using NDSolve initial conditions as parameters for a function and then a replacement rule

Tags: differential-equations, replacement, functional

I am trying to make a function based on two initial conditions of a set of differential equations:

```
sol[a, b] := 
NDSolve[{x1'[t] == ..., y1'[t] == ..., z1'[t] == ..., 
         x2'[t] == ..., y2'[t] == ..., z2'[t] == ...,
         p1'[t] == ..., p2'[t] == ..., p3'[t] == ...,
         e1'[t] == ..., e2'[t] == ..., e3'[t] == ...
         x2[0] == a, y2[0] == b (*insert other initial conditions here*)},
{x2[t], y2[t], z2[t], x1[t], y1[t], z1[t], p1[t], p2[t], p3[t], 
e1[t], e2[t], e3[t]}, {t, 0, T}];
```

However, this gives the error "NDSolve::ndinnt: Initial condition a is not a number or a rectangular array of numbers."

I also want to use this function as a replacement rule in order to plot a contour graph giving the value of e1[c] (for a certain fixed c) based on variables a and b:

```
(*c is some constant*)
g = e1[c] /. sol2[a, b];
ContourPlot[g, {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}]
```

But, this results in another error "ReplaceAll::reps: NDSolve[...] is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing."

Any way to explain (and hopefully fix) these two errors?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Try `ParametricNDSolve`.

Comment: Did the answer below answer your question? If so, please accept it by checking the grey checkmark next to the answer!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by `bbgodfrey` in a comment, you can use [`ParametricNDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html). As a toy example, let's do the following:

```
sols = ParametricNDSolve[{
  x'[t] == -x[t]
  , y'[t] == -y[t]
  , e'[t] == -e[t] + x[t]/y[t]
  , x[0] == a, y[0] == b , e[0] == 0
 }
 , {x, y, e}
 , {t, 0, 5}
 , {a, b}
]
```

Then

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[e[a, b][c] /. sols /. c -> 1], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}]
```

results in

[image]

***Notes about OP's code***

You can actually make your method work. It's not advisable, since it will be *much* slower due to calling `NDSolve` for every unique pair of `a` and `b`. Nonetheless, here's how you would go about doing it (included for the purpose of learning more about MMA by explaining what went wrong):

```
Clear[sols]
sols[a_, b_] := NDSolve[{x'[t] == -x[t]
  , y'[t] == -y[t]
  , e'[t] == -e[t] + x[t]/y[t]
  , x[0] == a, y[0] == b , e[0] == 0
 }
 , {x, y, e}
 , {t, 0, 5}
];
ContourPlot[e[1] /. sols[a, b], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}]
```

We define the function using `SetDelayed` (`:=`) due to the fact that `NDSolve` requires values for `a` and `b` in order to run. By using `Set` (`=`), MMA will try to run `NDSolve` immediately, even though `a` and `b` aren't defined as numbers. This is the reason for the first error.

We have also included underscores in the definition of `sols`: `sols[a_, b_]` instead of `sols[a, b]`. This is the way that MMA "functions" are defined. If you use `a` and `b` in the definition, then the right-hand side will be set to `sols[a, b]` *literally*, and you will not be able to change the values of `a` and `b`. Using the `Pattern`s `a_` and `b_` tells MMA that whatever you put in place of `a_` and `b_` will be fed to `a` and `b` in the right-hand-side expression.

As an example, look at the output when you run the following:

```
Clear[f, a, b]
f[a, b] = a + b
f[1, 2]
Clear[f, a, b]
f[a_, b_] = a + b
f[1, 2]
```

Finally, the second error comes about because you tried to evaluate `NDSolve` without specifying values for `a` and `b`. When you do this, MMA will just return the original expression and set it equal to `sols[a,b]`. Thus, when you try to use it as a replacement rule in your call to `ContourPlot`, it's not understood because expressions with `NDSolve` as a `Head` are not replacement rules.